# how can i add data to rows of an existing excel.csv file? excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a report i get every 4 hours. this report is same name. CM.csv i cant figure out how i can add the next reports data to my existing workbook worksheet CM.  without over writing existing data.  it doesnt matter if i miss a report because the next report will have my missing data. (24 hr period) - i get 6 reports all data that has happened since midnight.   i get 2AM, 6AM, 10AM, 2PM,6PM,10PM.  so by 10 PM i have 22 hrs worth of data.

I want the data from the /directory/CM.csv to be added to my SR.xlsx each time i open it without adding (duplicating) existing data to the report.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the data to the end of the data rows. You can find the last row of data by using:

```
first_row_to_enter_data_on = Sheets(name).Cells(Count.Rows,1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```